How can exceed CPU utilization 100% of Pod even though set request, limit 1000m?
Why does CPU utilization exceed 100%?
deployment.yaml
I restrict pod CPU utilization as 1000m.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 1000m
  limits:
    cpu: 1000m

promql
node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{namespace="$namespace", pod=~"$PodPrefix-.*", container!=""}

Grafana
I added dashboard naming Pod CPU Usage. It shows each pod CPU Utilization. It seems that some pod CPU utilization exceeds the limit (100%): 140%, even 215% .
How could it happen even though I set CPU requests and limit as 1000m?

Each pod consists of single container
